# JAVA - Trying to generate every number between 1 and 100000000000 and put into a txt file, and I'm getting the GC Overhead limit

Tags: java, memory-leaks, numbers

I understand the issue, but I'm not sure how to resolve it.

```
public static List<String> getNumbersInRange(long start, long end) {
    
    for (long i = start; i < end; i++) {
        String padded = String.format("%012d", i);
        result.add(padded);
    }
    
    return result;

}
```

Above is the number generator, and below is the file generator. How can I do this so that I don't get a memory leak?

```
long value = 1L;
    long value1 = 100000000001L;
    
    getNumbersInRange(value,value1);
    
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("UPC.txt"));
     
    for(String str: result) {
      writer.write(str + System.lineSeparator());
    }
    writer.close();
```

Forgive me if this isn't well thought out, I haven't done any programming in awhile.

Comment: You don't have a "memory leak", you're trying to hold everything in memory at once, and that's a huge number of items. Instead, either write the numbers immediately from your loop or use an `IntStream`.

Answer (score 3):

1. You won't be able to hold 100_000_000_000 long numbers in the list because the size of any collection/array in Java is integer, thus it cannot contain more than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` items.
2. In order to print the mentioned range into a file, it would take `1,088,888,888,890` digits in plain number format plus `100,000,000,000` delimiters to separate the numbers thus it would take over `1,107` GB of the disk space.  Assuming that your HDD is able to write at speed 100 MB/s, it would take over 3 hours to write this file.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having a function which returns the list of strings you want to print, you should write a function which prints the strings to the file as you generate them. This way you do not have to store a giant list in memory.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
long value = 1L;
long value1 = 100000000001L;
LongStream.rangeClosed(value, value1)
                .forEach(val -> {
                    try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("UPC.txt", true));){
                        writer.write(String.format("%012d", val) + System.lineSeparator());
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                });
```

This way,

1. You dont save in-memory data
2. Data is autogenerated for you
3. FileWriter constructor should have second parameter as true to indicate you want to append to the file

Comment: Absolutely don't reopen the file for each of billions of numbers!